# How do I use the GLI 2.0 ruby gem to accept ARGF data?

Tags: ruby, command-line, gli-gem

I've created my own gem using the [GLI 2.0 gem](http://davetron5000.github.com/gli/) for all the nice command line structure. It's working fine, but I'd also like to support data piped in.

```
my_prog new some_file # this is ok already
some_process | my_prog # how do I add this?
```

Somewhere I need to check how it was called (somehow) and then act appropriately. I've simplified a little, but my current code is below.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'gli'

include GLI::App

desc 'My example'
command :new do |c|
  desc 'Specify input file'
  arg_name 'filename'
  c.flag [:i,:input]

  c.action do |global_options,options,args|
    exit_now!("Input file must be specified") if options[:o].nil?
    exit_now!("New failed") unless File.exists?(options[:o])
  end
end

exit run(ARGV)
```

Comment: what happens when you just try to use ARGF inside an action block?  GLI modifies ARGV, so I think it should work although I haven't tried it.  The ARGF docs indicate that mutations of ARGV Do have an effect

Comment: I haven't tried that yet. Given that I haven't specified a command, how would it know which one to use? I know which one to use, but I don't know how to specify. I did think about setting a default, but I like the current default behaviour of displaying help.

Comment: ARGF is pretty flexible (see https://gist.github.com/3658622), but for what you're trying my_prog needs a command to know what to do.  If you gave it one, GLI will remove it from ARGV while parsing, ARGF should work as advertised.

Comment: That works fine. Thanks for the help. I cheated slightly and used a different command for piping so it's kept separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to sum up the discussion above:

GLI currently mutates `ARGV`, so `ARGF` should work fine inside the `action` block of a command, even if you're piping in.  BUT, GLI does require some sort of command to run, even if it's overriding the default of `help` to the command in question.